# Accessing VirtualBox with NAT adapter using SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtualbox, nat

I have a CentOs 6.5 running on a VirtualBox. I am using NAT adapter and my `inet addr` is `10.0.2.15` But, I can't access this host using `ssh root@10.0.2.15` I get `ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Bad file number` error.

Is there anyway to access a server using NAT adapter using ssh from putty?

Comment: Ensure you have a functioning SSH server running on the host machine and ensure your port 22 is forwarding onto the internal IP of the host. If these are configured correctly you can SSH from guest to host.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams All my settings are [described here](http://superuser.com/questions/738196/unable-to-access-localhost-internet-using-one-adapter-in-centos/) My port is 8080. That means, currently I am able to log in using `127.0.0.1:8080` but unfotunately I can't access thought ssh with this settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another port forward to virtualbox with:

```
Host IP 127.0.0.1 Host Port 2222 Guest IP 10.0.2.15 Guest port 22
```

Then ssh to port 2222 on 127.0.0.1

Rinse and repeat for any other ports required, remembering that the port cannot be <1024 on the host side.

Comment: How on earth do you send a port forward onto a loopback address? All you will get here is a timeout from your router.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams It seems like he is right. I worked like a charm. I am able to access it now.

Comment: It's on the virtual box side with a NAT setup; it is counter intuitive, but it works. The loopback in this case is the host machine's loopback, which can talk to the guest machine via it's NAT'd ip.

Comment: This seems very strange, but if it works I suppose....

Comment: @metacom Unfortunately, things are a bit worse when it comes to sharing folders. I used to use samba to share foders between virutual box and Windows 7. Now, I am unable too. Any way to remedy this problem?