# How to share folders b/n VirtualBox and Win 7 using NAT adapter and Samba

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, samba, nat

When I had my Adapter set to `Host Only` I followed [**this tutorial**](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/how-to-install-samba-server-on-centos-6/) and was able to view the folder `# \samba\share\` only buy typing `\\192.168.55.444` in my windows start up. So, this means I could share this folder without any problem between two machines. But, now that I have switched to [NAT adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/738196/unable-to-access-localhost-internet-using-one-adapter-in-centos), and my `ifconfig eth0` shows this as the host address `10.0.2.15` I am unable to access my samba shared folder no matter how I try to access it.

Comment: So, the folder that you want to share is on the guest, and you want to access it from the host? Or do I have that backwards?

Comment: Also, why can't you continue using the host-only adapter? Why do you want to change it?

Comment: @Kenster Thanks for the response. I was able to share folders using [this approach](http://superuser.com/questions/739141/trying-to-share-folder-in-centos-after-installing-guest-addtitions).