# Trying to share folder in CentOs after installing guest Addtitions

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, centos, samba

I have VirtualBox 4.3.10 running a Minimal CentOS 6.5 using NAT adapter in my Win 7 .

I have installed Guest Additions and I am trying to share `Drive E:` as you can see in this picture.

[image]

Next I went to `My Computer > MAP NETWORK DRIVE` I can't add a drive with any letter by doing `\\vboxsrv\E_DRIVE`

I also have samba installed. How can I share folders with Guest Additions and Samba installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you're trying to mount the folder in Windows.  You need to mount the folder in your CentOS guest.  The [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_manual) has a good description of how to do this.  The key piece is you have to mount the shared folder using this command:

```
mount -t vboxsf sharename mountpoint
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now. I supposed `sharename` is the folder I want to share in windows and `mountpoint` is the folder inside my `/root` directory? Plus. Does this work with NAT Adapter?

Comment: The `sharename` is the name you gave the share when you created it in VirtualBox, "E_DRIVE" in  your example.  The mount point is where in the guest's file system you want to mount the folder, usually something like `/mnt/` or `/media/e_drive`. And yes, shared folders are not affected in any way by the networking mode you use, so it will work with NAT.

Comment: You are a life saver. I wish I could upvote this a 100 times if it was possible. I love you, totally in a manly way :)

Comment: Will this setting work, even if I unstalled samba ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't use Windows file sharing like the Windows guest does.  It uses a new filesystem type (`vboxsf`) which communicates directly with the host through the guest additions.

Comment: Is samba really faster. I think I read that somewhere.

Comment: I doubt it, but i haven't seen any benchmarks.