# Hiding port number from address.

Tags: centos, port-forwarding, port, tcp, vps

I have centos 6.5 running some web apps. Currently due the following port forwarding rules, I am only able to access my public content using `127.0.0.1:8080/`[image]

Is there anyone to just use `127.0.0.1` instead? I can't do anything with hosts file because this is not a host problem, but rather the port.

Any fixes for this problem?

Comment: Why would you forward port 80 to guest port 22 ? just put your things right and make the host port 80 available...

Comment: no, because you wasted your port 80 mapping on ssh. when you put an address without a port into a web browser, it assumes that you mean port 80. I'd recommend you map 22 -> 22 and 80 -> 80, unless you have some good reason to mangle the ports as they run through your nat. either way, don't host a high value service (ssh) behind the single most likely to be scanned port there is (80). its counterproductive from a security perspective.

Comment: @Kwaio Because NAT is using IP `10.0.2.15` and this can't be accessed from my browser for some reason I don't understand. I tried for weeks, but I can't access my server with that IP. so I am forwarding port 80 to 22.

Comment: @FrankThomas How do you access ssh then? Because I can't use any port using the eth0 IP that NAT gives me. which is 10.0.2.15

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, reconfigure your rule to map 22 -> 22 and run 'ssh 127.0.0.1'. then set your 8080 -> 80 `http://127.0.0.1/`. you know, all of this would be SOOOO much easier if you used a bridged network connection

Comment: @FrankThomas Trust me. It's actually easier to build a real bridge than to create a bridge network in CentOs. I gave up after 3 months (on/off) trying. But, I will test your answer now.

Comment: I'm suprised that centos has problems with it. its a virtualbox feature, and works basically the same in windows as it does in the debian distros I use, so its suprising you would have issues. as for your ports, just remember, 80 -> 80, and 22 -> 22.

Comment: No offense meant, but I think you misunderstand us partially because you really lack basic network/system/OS knowledge. Do you understand how NAT works ? "bridged" in virtualbox means your VM will act as if it was a real server connected directly to the LAN.

Comment: @FrankThomas `+1` You saved me. I finally have Vbox working without errors in months. I got the bad advices [here](http://superuser.com/questions/738196/unable-to-access-localhost-internet-using-one-adapter-in-centos) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/736847/does-a-virtualbox-centos-need-two-adapters-to-work-properly)

Comment: @Kwaio No offense taken. I am self-taught in the process. I made the change from WAMP to VPS recently. In my online un-managed VPS server, everything works fine, but not on Vbox.

Comment: @FrankThomas Please answer, so I can't accept that answer. I finally feel relieved. Now, I am only a front end web developer. This port, network stuff is too hard.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a working solution. You should think about having a skilled friend/colleague on hand for that kind of matters. Also, don't wait month before asking here, we're here to help =)